Mongo server error: invalid namespace specified while uploading data using postman
{MongoServerError: Invalid namespace specified: /ytDB.users} getting this error whenever i try to pass data from the postman
app.js file
import express from "express";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";


const app = express();
// app.use is used when we want to use a middleware in our applications or when we need to do a configuration settings in our application.
app.use(cors({
    origin:process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
    credentials:true

}))


// CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a security feature implemented by web browsers to control how web pages can request resources from a different domain than the one that served the web page. It is a mechanism that allows servers to specify who can access their resources and how those resources can be accessed.

 app.use(express.json({limit:"32kb"}))
 // limiting the size of the json data that can be sent to the server - Prevents server from crashing
 app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true,limit:"32kb"}))
 //above line is used to limit the size of the data that can be sent to the server through the url encoding
 app.use(express.static("public"))
 //public is the name of the folder where all the static files are stored like images, videos, etc.
 app.use(cookieParser())
 // above line is used to add cookies and modify it from my server to users browser and perform crud  operations on it.


 //routes import

 import userRouter from './routes/user.routes.js';

 // routes declaration

 app.use('/api/v1/users',userRouter)


export default app;

dotenv config file
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import connect_DB from './db/index.js';
import app from './app.js'
// import express from 'express';

// You used the dotenv module to load environment variables from a .env file into process.env. This allows you to manage configuration settings outside of your code, making it easier to change settings without modifying the source code.
// const app = express();
dotenv.config({
    path: "./.env"
})
 

connect_DB()
.then((result) => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT ||8000,()=>{
        console.log(`server is running at port ${process.env.PORT}`)
    })
    
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Mongo db conncetion failed",err)
});

constants.js file
export const DB_NAME = "youtube-clone";

database conncetion file
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { DB_NAME } from "../constants.js";


const connect_DB = async () => {


    try {
        const uri = `${process.env.MONGODB_URI}/{DB_NAME}`;
        console.log(`Connection to mongo db is in progress at ${uri}`)
        const connectionInstance = await mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGODB_URI}/${DB_NAME}`);
        console.log(`connection successfull to ${connectionInstance.connection.host}`);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error aya hai", error)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}



export default connect_DB;

user.controller.js
// import asyncHandler from '../utils/asyncHandler.js';
import ApiError from "../utils/ApiError.js";
import asyncHandler from "../utils/asyncHandler.js";
// import { User } from "../models/user.models.js";
import { uploadOnCloudinary } from "../services/cloudinary.js";
import { ApiResponse } from "../utils/ApiResponse.js";
import {User} from "../models/user.models.js";

// below function is used to register a user
// The registerUser function is created in the src/controllers/user.controller.js file. The registerUser function is an asynchronous function that takes the request and response objects as arguments. The registerUser function sends a response with a status code of 200 and a JSON object with a message property set to "ok".

// this is a controller function to register a user
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  // res.status(200).json({
  //   message: "ok",
  // });
  //getting user details from frontend
  const { fullname, email, password, username } = req.body;
  console.log("email:", email);

  // validating the user details that are not empty
  if (
    [fullname, email, password, username].some((field) => field?.trim() === "")
  ) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "Please fill in all fields");
  }
  // checking if the user already exists in the database

  existedUser = await User.findOne({
    // the $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more expressions and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the expressions. this is specially used to check if the user already exists in the database
    $or: [{ username }, { email }]
  });

  if (existedUser) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "User already exists");
  }
  // By the below code we are checking for images and avatars and getting the local path of the images and avatars that are uploaded by user and storing them in the variables avatarLocalPath and coverImageLocalPath

  // this is necessary to access the files that are uploaded by the user
  const avatarLocalPath = req.files?.avatar[0]?.path;
  // const coverImageLocalPath = req.files?.coverImage[0]?.path;

  // checking avatar properly that we are getting it ao not

  if (!avatarLocalPath) {
    throw new ApiError(400, " Please upload an avatar");
  }
  // uploading the avatar and cover image to cloudinary by calling the uploadOnCloudinary function
  const avatar = await uploadOnCloudinary(avatarLocalPath);
  const coverImage = await uploadOnCloudinary(coverImageLocalPath);

  // checking if the avatar is uploaded successfully or not because it is a mandatory field and if it is not uploaded successfully then the database will crash
  if (!avatar) {
    throw new ApiError(500, "Avatar not uploded please check and reupload");
  }
  // creating a user object with all the check data and saving it to the database
  const user = await User.create({
    fullname,
    avatar: avatar.url,
    coverImage: coverImage?.url || "",
    email,
    password,
    username: username.toLowerCase(),
  });

  //removing the password and refresh token field from the response
  const createdUser = await user.findById(user._id).select("-password -refreshToken");
  // checking if the user is created successfully or not
  if (!createdUser) {
    throw new ApiError(500, "Something went wrong while registering the user");
  }

  // returning the response with status code 200 and user object
  return res.status(201).json(new ApiResponse(200, createdUser, "User registered successfully"));
});

export default registerUser;

user.models.js file
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            lowercase: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true
        },
        email:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            lowercase:true,
            unique:true,
            trim:true
        },
        fullname:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            trim:true
        },
        avatar:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        },
        coverImage:{
            type:String,
        },
        password:{
            type:String,
            required:[true,"Password is required"],
            unique:true,
            trim:true,
            lowercase:true
        },
        watchHistory:[
            {
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:"Video"
            }
        ],
        refreshToken:{
            type:String
        }

    },
    {
        timestamps:true
    }
)
// this is a middleware that will run before saving the user to the database
userSchema.pre("save",async function(next){

    if(!this.isModified("password")){
      return next();
    }
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password,10);
    next()
})
// this method  compares as=nd return true or false if the password is correct
userSchema.methods.isPasswordCorrect =async function(password){
    return await bcrypt.compare(password,this.password)
}

// this method generates an access token
userSchema.methods.generateAccessToken = function(){
    return jwt .sign(
        { //payload
            _id:this._id,
            email:this.email,
            username:this.username,
            fullname:this.fullname
        },//secret key
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {//options
            expiresIn:process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRY
        }
    )
}
// this method generates a refresh token
 userSchema.methods.generaterefreshToken  =function (){
    return jwt.sign(
        {
            _id:this._id,
           
        },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {
            expiresIn:process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRY
        }
    )
 }
export const User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

user.routes.js
import { Router } from "express";
import  registerUser  from "../controllers/user.controller.js";
import { upload } from "../middlewares/multer.middleware.js";

// adding the multers middleware to the route
const router = Router();
router.route("/register").post(
    //injecting the middleware before the .post method above is executed
upload.fields([
    {name:"avatar",
    maxcount:1},
    {
        name:"coverImage",
        maxCount:1
    }
    //the middleware is injected here to handel the image uploads and avatar uploads it ensures the files are processed and available in the request object before the controller function is executed
]) ,   
    registerUser
)


export default router;

please help me about this error i have tried everything to best of my knowledge

What does the log line Connection to mongo db is in progress at look like?

it took me some time but it figured it out
i just wanted to remove the slash after the mongodb.net/ in.env file
before
MONGODB_URI= mongodb+srv://ruhith:Ruhith123@youtube.ryqmd.mongodb.net/
After
MONGODB_URI= mongodb+srv://ruhith:Ruhith123@youtube.ryqmd.mongodb.net

Please change your database username and password. Stack Overflow is public site.
